# How to call upon code or go to a spot in code. Java

Tags: java

I have 6 different methods of calculations written in my code so far. I want to ask the user for input so that they can type either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or Diamond, Gold, Iron, Elder, Wither, Dragon and go to a specific region of my code and/or run the calculation associate with their answer. I know how to validate input (supposedly) so do not worry about that. If you need any further information or would like to see the code just ask me :-)

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sound like a good use for the [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement.

Comment: It's not that we would **like** to see the code, we **need** to see the code. How can we help with your code if we don't see it?

Comment: He says he wants to ask the user for input, but he already knows how to validate input. Maybe he's asking for how to get the input??

Comment: You guys with questions should re-read my question. AntonH and ahitt6345 @user3437460.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         System.out.println("Enter your choice: 1, 2, 3 etc..");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = sc.nextInt();
            switch (input) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("1: do your stuff here");
                    //do your stuff here
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("2: do your stuff here");
                    //do your stuff here
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice");
           }
    }
```

Comment: now how would I go about putting this into a loop if the numbers 1-6 were not inputed?

Answer (score 1):

> I have 6 different methods of calculations written in my code so far. I want to ask the user for input so that they can type either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or Diamond, Gold, Iron, Elder, Wither, Dragon and go to a specific region of my code and/or run the calculation associate with their answer.

To go to "specific region" of your code, break your tasks into separate methods, then use switch case to invoke specific method according to the input:

```
switch(input){
    case 1: task1();
            break;
    case 2: task2();
            break;
    case 3: task3();
            break;
    case 4: task4();
            break;
    case 5: task5();
            break;
    case 6: task6();
            break;
}

public static void task1(){
    //things to do when user input is 1
}


public static void task2(){
    //things to do when user input is 2
}

//...and so on
```